# Optaplanner: Reproducible solution

Tags: optaplanner

I am trying to solve a problem similar to employee rostering. The problem I am facing is every time I run the solver, it generates a different assignment. This makes it harder to debug why a particular case was picked over another. Why is this the case?

P.S. My assignment has many hard constraint and all of them may not be satisfied (most cases I still see some negative hard score). So my termination strategy is based on `unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit`. Could this be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's likely the termination. OptaPlanner's default `environmentMode` guarantees the exact same solution at the exact same step (*). But CPU cycles differ a lot from run to run, so that means you get more or less steps per run. Use `DEBUG` logging to see that.

Use `stepCountLimit` or `unimprovedStepCountLimit` termination.

(*) Unless specified otherwise in the docs. Simulated Annealing for example will be different even in the exact same step if used with time bound terminations.

Comment: Thanks. I see unimprovedStepCountLimit can only be used in localSearch. What does that mean? I am not defining any phases explicitly.